# How to pass by reference using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to change an address variable　when I push a button based on a postal code variable.
I mean changing a postal code to an address.

```
struct CustomerForm: View {
    //@State var postalCode:String = ""
    //@State var address:String = ""

    @ObservedObject var getAddress = GetAddress()

    var body: some View {
       VStack{
          TextField("PostalCode", text: $getAddress.postalCode)
                            
          Button(action: {
             getAddress.postalCodeToAddress()
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Search")
                        })
                    }
         TextField("Address", text: $getAddress.address)
       }
    }
}
```

```
extension CLGeocoder {

    struct Address {
        var administrativeArea: String?
        var locality: String?
        var subLocality: String?
    }

    func convertAddress(from postalCode: String, completion: @escaping (Address?, Error?) -> Void) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(postalCode) { (placemarks, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                let location = CLLocation(
                    latitude: (placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude)!,
                    longitude: (placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
                )
                 CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
                    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first, error == nil else {
                        completion(nil, error)
                        return
                    }
                    var address: Address = Address()
                    address.administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea
                    address.locality = placemark.locality
                    address.subLocality = placemark.subLocality
                    completion(address, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class GetAddress{
    @Published var postalCode = ""
    @Published var address = ""
    //var postalCode: String
    //var address: String
    //init(postalCode: String, address: String) {
    //    self.postalCode = postalCode
    //    self.address = address
    // }
    
    func postalCodeToAddress(){
            CLGeocoder().convertAddress(from: postalCode) { (result, error)  ->Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                if let result = result,let administrativeArea = result.administrativeArea,let locality = result.locality,let subLocality = result.subLocality{
                    self.address = administrativeArea + locality + subLocality
                }  
            }
    }
}
```

In CustomerForm view, I initialize GetAddress class, and I call convertAddress　method.
I pass the address variable in CustomerForm struct, but it doesn't reflect.
Why? How to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: `class` would have to be an `ObservableObject` and the variables that you want to use to trigger UI updates will need `@Published`

Comment: I see. I edited the above script. It did work. I have a question. In fact my code, `postalCode` and `address`  in CustomerForm are binding variables. So how do I pass those to GetAddress class? Now GetAddress class has empty variables like this `@Published var postalCode = "" ` . Thank you.

Comment: You can't use `Binding` in a `class` only a SwiftUI `View`